# How to structure api endpoint for response and access by permissions and access points

Tags: json, rest, http, api-design

I am building an API, where users have a public and private access for the same resources, and am stuck thinking of the best way to handle this based on access points or domain path.

What would be the best way to go?

1. Separate URLs, one for each situation, e.g.:

   - `/videos`: for anonymous users and authenticated users including resource owner from public domain or path, e.g: `example.com/home`.
   - `mgt/videos` or `/videos/mgt` or `/videos-mgt`: for admin (superuser) or resource owner in dashboard path. e.g: `dashboard.example.com` or `example.com/dashboard`.
2. same URL with a parameter to differentiate each case.

   - `/videos`: for anonymous users and authenticated users including resource owner from public domain path, e.g: `example.com`.
   - `/videos?mode=mgt`: for admin (superuser) or resource owner in dashboard path, e.g: `dashboard.example.com` or `example.com/dashboard`.

**Key Note**: same user can access resources from either public or dashboard (private) route on the domain, both responses and access are different based on the access point, permission and resource ownership, e.g. admin (superuser) or resource owner accessing the resource from the dashboard path.

I have tried both methods, the first seems to not be in line with the idea of having a single API resource entrypoint, inorder to allow easy management and prevent duplicate codes.

The second on the other hand, seems to raise my doubt about the correct use of GET request parameters and whether I am in violation of it's actual use, introducing a possible future bug or if it poses a security risk.

I am really curious what way to go, whether it be one of these two or an entirely different opinion.